# How to limit data usage of individual apps?

Tags: data-monitoring, firewall

There are many apps out there to limit data usage of *entire* system. Using Firewall, I can block an app from accessing Internet, too.

But, I don't want these. I want to limit data usage of individual apps. e.g. - AppX should be firewalled if it comsumes 1GB within a day or month etc.
How can I achieve this?

I am rooted on ICS. I have tried to use Tasker but without luck.